# Can't shift focus to unshown CardLayout JPanel

Tags: java, swing, focus

Why can't I shift focus to an unshown `JPanel` card in a `CardLayout`?

I'm implementing a `CardLayout`-based interface that needs to be keyboard navigation friendly. When a user finishes tabbing through all the fields on one card, the user needs to be able to tab to the next card.

I've already implemented a `FocusTraversalPolicy` that produces the right `Component` at each point in the process, and a `FocusAdapter` to pop up any cards newly tabbed to, but something is eating the messages and preventing focus change.

I *can* uncleanly pass the `CardLayout` to the `FocusTraversalPolicy` to change the card— though any of its functions are called several times in Swing's many threads and leads to strange behavior. Besides, that way's just dirty.

I *do not* want to use key bindings b/c that would require reimplementing all of the focus work Java already does for me, and is also really unclean.

Basically: Java dislikes shifting focus to unshown cards in `CardLayout`s— **how can I override this?**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a wizard-like UI.  If so, add a "Next" button as the last field on each card.

The action of the Next button would be to flip to the next card as set focus to the first entry field.

The last entry field on each card would transfer focus to the Next button, who could then be "pressed" with a strike of the spacebar when it receives focus (which is the default behavior of a JButton), keeping it keyboard-friendly.

This would alleviate the need for special KeyBindings or FocusTraversalPolicies.

**EDIT:**

Try this, using FocusListeners for the JTextFields. Tab thorugh the fields and the cards will flip to the next one automatically once you tab out of the last field. You could use ActionListeners instead if you wish:

**EDIT 2:** Added hack for panels that only have 1 field.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo2 implements Runnable
{
  final static String CARD1 = "One";
  final static String CARD2 = "Two";
  final static String CARD3 = "Three";

  JPanel cards;
  CardLayout cardLayout;
  JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5;
  JButton dummy;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutDemo2());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    tf2 = new JTextField(10);
    tf2.addFocusListener(new CardFlipper(CARD2));

    tf3 = new JTextField(10);
    tf4 = new JTextField(10);
    tf4.addFocusListener(new CardFlipper(CARD3));

    tf5 = new JTextField(10);
    tf5.addFocusListener(new CardFlipper(CARD1));

    dummy = new JButton()
    {
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize()
      {
        return new Dimension(0,0);
      }
    };

    dummy.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
      {
        dummy.transferFocus();
      }
    });

    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    card1.add(new JLabel("One"));
    card1.add(tf1);
    card1.add(new JLabel("Two"));
    card1.add(tf2);

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add(new JLabel("Three"));
    card2.add(tf3);
    card2.add(new JLabel("Four"));
    card2.add(tf4);

    JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
    card3.add(dummy);
    card3.add(new JLabel("Five"));
    card3.add(tf5);    

    cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    cards.add(card1, CARD1);
    cards.add(card2, CARD2);
    cards.add(card3, CARD3);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("CardLayout Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(180, 200);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class CardFlipper extends FocusAdapter
  {
    private String nextCard;

    CardFlipper(String cardName)
    {
      this.nextCard = cardName;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
    {
      cardLayout.show(cards, nextCard);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, this is undesirable. The interface will be deployed for the visually impaired, and it would be a confusing paradigm to need to double-tap `space` or `enter` to advance.

Comment: Double-tap the spacebar? Who said that? It would be a single press when the button has focus. This is standard desktop UI behavior, regardless of the language it's written in (Swing, Visual Basic, etc.). I'm not sure how standard out-of-the-box functionality (that's industry standard) would be confusing.

Comment: Moreover, if I navigate to the last field of a form, enter my data, and tab/enter/whatever away from the field, and the UI automagically switches the UI on the user w/o warning would seem confusing to me.  Don't surprise the user.  Your UI should be obvious.

Comment: Again, this is for the visually impaired. In that context, where there is no visual element, a "button" is a meaningless concept that simply necessitates an extra button press— specifically, it means tabbing from the last data field to the `Next` button, then pressing `enter` to move to the next pane. 

Considering this constraint, it makes no sense to have an extra button— there is *no* "UI switching" apparent to the user.

Besides, tabbing is analogous to continue, especially in visually impaired contexts.

Comment: Then why the Cardlayout?  Just have one, long, scrolling form. You could programmatically scroll as the user advances.

Comment: I want to keep the program compartmentalized, as it runs in distinct steps. I *could* programmatically scroll, I *could* add a button, but I want to use the built-in focus system in a way that makes sense and is not possible by default.

Comment: That is really helpful, but it fails on shift-tab. I'll try working on this and edit your post when I'm done.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. It requires at least two elements per pane.

Comment: +1, for the general approach. `This does not resolve the issue. It requires at least two elements per pane` you have been given an approach, that you may need to customize the solution for your exact requirements. We are only here to get you started, not write the entire code for you.

Comment: `It requires at least two elements per pane.` No, not necessarily.  Further, it really sounds like you don't need a CardLayout. Are you aware that you can "compartmentalize" your panels using `TitledBorders`?

Comment: @splungebob `No it doesn't` ... don't really know how to respond to that... it does. Comment out an `.add`. Your code works by focusing back on the previous TextField (as that is the only one that Java can focus on) and using that event to switch cards.

Comment: That's why I said, "not necessarily".  You'd have to do a little work.  One way would be to switch to an `ActionListener` instead of a `FocusListener`.

Comment: But seriously, why are you stuck on CardLayout?  It does not seem to be the right tool for the job.

Comment: `ActionListener` would fragment keyboard controls into "things possible through tab" and "things possible through enter." This is not optimal.

Comment: I'm willing to consider alternatives to `CardLayout`— my requirement is being able to switch panels by changing focus. A one page layout is not possible for this program's context.

Comment: `It requires at least two elements per pane.` See edit #2 for a hackish workaround.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to keep the program compartmentalized, as it runs in distinct steps.

This does not prevent you from creating a long scrolling form?

You can still create individual panels the way you are doing now. Then instead of adding these panels to a CardLayout where you need to swap panels, you can add the panels to a panel using a BoxLayout (or GridBagLayout).

This would even give more flexibility since each panel can be of a different size without impacting the size of every individual panel.

However, forms do not currently scroll automatically in a JScrollPane, so you may want to check out [Scrolling a Form](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/scrolling-a-form/) for a class this will do this for you.

Comment: I'm also unsure that a scrolling UI would be appropriate for the visually impaired, especially if it requires, essentially, appropriating a scroll wheel.

Comment: @citelao, Who said anything about a scroll wheel? You just use Tab or Shift-Tab. You requirement was to move from panel to panel by using the tab key. You either have to manage the swapping of the panels (as suggested by splungebob) or manage the scrolling of the form (as this suggests). You could even hide the scrollbars.

Comment: This approach might confuse someone who has no experience with UI concepts— how would such a user correct if they accidentally scroll the pane? Scrolling a form by definition mimics a scroll wheel.

Comment: `how would such a user correct if they accidentally scroll the pane?` - You could hide the scrollbars.

Comment: What about a scroll wheel? Non-sighted users *have no concept of scroll panes*

Comment: if you don't show the scrollbar then the scroll wheel doesn't work. However, the viewport will still scroll if you use the Page-Up, Page-Down keys on the keyboard. However, having said that, "scrolling the pane" does NOT cause the text field to lose focus. So any data that is typed will still be typed into the current text field. Then the next time you TAB you will move to the next text field and that text field will automatically be scrolled into view. I can't tell you what is a better UI, I can just suggest the class which gives you an option. Try the demo code.

Comment: `Non-sighted users have no concept of scroll panes` How do they have a concept of different panels then? Is there a "sound" every time a new panel is display so they can track there location in the input process? `my requirement is being able to switch panels by changing focus.` - the only requirement I've seen is to be able to use the Tab key to move to the next "input field" for the user.

Comment: Your proposed solution is to use one visible panel at time. You could use a panel with a GridLayout so each panel is the same size. Therefore scrolling from one panel to the other is like showing a different card.  I don't see the difference from a non-sighted point of view, unless you have some other means of telling the user what "card" is currently being displayed as you move from card to card, but I have not seen a requirement for that.

Comment: Again, I'm saying this is the best approach. It just seems to me like you are not separating your proposed solution from a true requirement.

Comment: Oops, my above comment should say: "I'm NOT saying...".